# Will Fortran 90 code always work with a Fortran 95 compiler?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

We have a complex program written in Fortran 90, I've only been able to find Fortran 95 compilers. Unfortunately I have limited access and experience but need immediate insight on the problem.

Will Fortran 90 code always compile correctly with a Fortran 95 compiler such as gfortran?

Comment: They don't have to be backwards compatible, but all of them that I know of are.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't worry - radical changes in Fortran happen roughly thrice per century.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fortran versions are backwards compatible, perhaps to a fault.  In the Fortran95 standard, there were some very (deservedly) obscure constructs that were finally deleted: eg, from [this page](http://sc.tamu.edu/IBM.Tutorial/docs/Compilers/xlf_8.1/html/lr424.HTM):

> Fortran 95 indicates that the following Fortran 90 and FORTRAN 77 features have been deleted:
>
> - ASSIGN and assigned GO TO statements
> - PAUSE statement
> - O control variables and expressions of type real
> - H edit descriptor
> - Branching to an END IF statement from outside the IF block

But unless your code uses those (and it shouldn't), you should be fine with F95; and otherwise, most F95 compilers will still have a mode with which you could compile that older code, eg `-std=legacy` for gfortran.

Comment: Also most compilers are well on their way to becoming Fortran 2003 compilers, that will still compile F90 code if you stay away from old obscure constructs, that were not deleted in F90 yet. In fact, the standards are carefully defined with backwards compatibility in mind and therefore compilers today are still capable to compile F77 or even older dialects. The relation of F95 to F90 in terms of deleted features will always be fixed as described by Jonathan. Though I would be more concerned with any new iteration, and as laid out, not even that is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fortran compilers, except IBM, are backwards compatible. So any valid F90 code will compile on an F95 compiler.

IBM does things differently, they seem to be forward compatible. So `xlf` will compile 77 onwards while `xlf90` will do 90/95, etc..

Note, **always** is a strong word. And it will really depend on your compiler maker. But GNU Fortran or Intel Fortran currently only have one compiler for all flavors of Fortran, although support for F2003/2008 is spotty sometimes.